# Multi-threading WPF on the UI

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

In my C# WPF application I have a `DataGrid` and right above it there is a `TextBox` for the user to search and filter the grid as they type. If the user types fast though, no text will appear until 2 seconds after they type because the UI thread is too busy updating the grid.

Since most of the delay is all on the UI side (i.e. filtering the datasource is nearly instant, but rebinding and re-rendering the grid is slow), multi-threading has not been helpful. I then tried setting the dispatcher of just the grid to be at a lower level while the grid gets updated, but this didn't solve the issue either. Here's some code... Any suggestions on how to solve this type of problem?

```
string strSearchQuery = txtFindCompany.Text.Trim();

this.dgCompanies.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle, new Action(delegate
    {
        //filter data source, then
        dgCompanies.ItemsSource = oFilteredCompanies;
    }));
```

Comment: Post your current XAML. Chances are that you're breaking UI virtualization and that's why the UI is "slow". And you should be using a `CollectionView` for this.

Comment: Yeah. As in: There are fast grids. The UI is single threaded, but 2 seconds is a lot - THIS should be looked into. Do not try to work around the real issue, which is a 2 second update to start with.

Comment: It's not virtualization.  I know because I can turn it off and will experience a much much longer load time.  It's 1-2 seconds because if the user quickly types the word "test", the grid gets rebound 4 times, one for each letter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are targeting .net 4.5, an option is to set the `Delay` property on your `TextBox` which will prevent setting the source value until a certain time threshold is met (until the user stops typing).

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SearchText, Delay=1000}"/>
```

This waits for 1 second after there is no user input to set the source value.

Another option is to have a button trigger your filter/search instead of when the textbox changes.

Answer (score 5):

Using a ListCollectionView as your ItemsSource for the grid and updating the Filter works much faster than re-assigning the ItemsSource.

The example below filters 100000 rows with no apparent lag by simply refreshing the View in the setter for the search term text property.

**ViewModel**

```
class ViewModel
    {
        private List<string> _collection = new List<string>(); 
        private string _searchTerm;

        public ListCollectionView ValuesView { get; set; }

        public string SearchTerm
        {
            get
            {
                return _searchTerm;
            }
            set
            {
                _searchTerm = value;
                ValuesView.Refresh();
            }
        }

        public ViewModel()
        {
            _collection.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(0, 100000).Select(p => Guid.NewGuid().ToString()));

            ValuesView = new ListCollectionView(_collection);
            ValuesView.Filter = o =>
                {
                    var listValue = (string)o;
                    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(_searchTerm) || listValue.Contains(_searchTerm);
                };
        }
    }
```

**View**

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding SearchTerm, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ValuesView}"
         Grid.Row="1" />
```

Comment: Thank you!  The delay suggested by Shoe resolved the issue, but I'll implement and test your suggestion as well and see if I get better performance.  Thanks again